# Deploy archiva on WildFly 8.1

Tags: apache, deployment, jboss, wildfly, archiva

First of all, i want to say i'm new in this.

I'm using WildFly 8.1, and i want to have a common repository of my own for all of my future projects (also working with maven), so i thought using Archiva (version 2.1.1). I've downloaded the .WAR file, deployed it in WildFly server, but when I try to enable, it throws an error. Here I copy the error:

```
Failed to enable apache-archiva-2.1.1.war.

Unexpected HTTP response: 500

Request
{
    "address" => [("deployment" => "apache-archiva-2.1.1.war")],
    "operation" => "deploy"
}

Response

Internal Server Error
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"apache-archiva-2.1.1.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"apache-archiva-2.1.1.war\".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"apache-archiva-2.1.1.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.archiva.redback.integration.taglib.jsp.IfConfiguredTag from [Module \"deployment.apache-archiva-2.1.1.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.archiva.redback.integration.taglib.jsp.IfConfiguredTag from [Module \"deployment.apache-archiva-2.1.1.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"}},
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with 2.1.1 release. I missed to remove a tld declaration file whereas we don't use anymore jsp/tld :-(
It's fixed in master.

You can try that with a dev version build here: https://builds.apache.org/view/A-D/view/Archiva/job/archiva-master-build/

This will be fixed for 2.1.2 version

Comment: i've downloaded archiva-webapp-2.1.2-SNAPSHOT.war, and i couldn't get it running on wildfly :(

Comment: Latest version of archiva is 2.2.1. It should be corrected, right?